# chaining variadic function calls

Tags: c++, c, variadic-functions

A `printf` function-like call from a function with variable number of arguments is easy enough to make - just use a *v*-version of those functions (`vprintf`, `vsprintf`, `CString::FormatV`, etc). But what if I'm chaining the calls up? Here's the simple code:

```
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <iostream>
void direct(const char * _fmt, bool _extra, ...){
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, _extra);

    char ca[200];
    vsprintf(ca, _fmt, args);
    std::cout << ca << std::endl;

    va_end(args);
}

void chained(const char * _fmt, ...){
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, _fmt);
    direct(_fmt, false, args);
    va_end(args);
}

int main(){
    direct("direct works just fine: %d", false, 1);
    chained("indirect produces garbage: %d", 1);
    return 0;
}
```

A sample output is as follows:

```
direct works just fine: 1
indirect produces garbage: 1951661256
```

I feel that I'm missing something obvious but can't figure it out thus far. Please help me fix it so that whether I call `direct` or `chained` the code works properly.

Flagged the question as C/C++ but I prefer a C++ answer (if there's a difference)

Comment: Don't use C-style variadic functions in C++. There are better alternatives.

Comment: There is a  comma missing before each  `...`.

Comment: @alk - Funny thing is, when prototypes were added to C++, the comma was optional. Then C implemented prototypes, but made the comma mandatory. But in C++ it's still optional.

Comment: @StoryTeller: Unbelievable ... *sigh*

Comment: @alk - Yup. I left it in my answer because it's tangential to the issue, but if this is meant to go into a C compatible header, that comma is gonna have to be there, you are 100% correct.

Comment: @n.m. yes, indeed there are, but the compatibility with C is a soft requirement in my case

Comment: I've added the commas :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I feel that I'm missing something obvious but can't figure it out thus far

You did. And it's something you actually started with: *"just use a v-version of those functions"*. The reason those functions got a v-version was to allow, as you called it, chaining them. So if you want to support it for your own printf-like function, make sure to follow the same practice:

```
void direct_v(const char * _fmt, bool _extra, va_list args){
    char ca[200];
    vsprintf(ca, _fmt, args);
    std::cout << ca << std::endl;
}

void direct(const char * _fmt, bool _extra...){
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, _extra);
    direct_v(_fmt, _extra, args);
    va_end(args);
}

void chained(const char * _fmt...){
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, _fmt);
    direct_v(_fmt, false, args);
    va_end(args);
}
```

A nice emerging property of splitting `direct` like this is that you get better separation of  concerns. The wrapper does the `va_list` related bit, and the v-function only cares about what needs to be done with the list, which is what allows for reuse here.

---

Pre-edit note: BTW, if C compatibility is indeed a concern, the function prototypes need a comma to separate the last argument from the ellipsis. The syntax you used is C++ only.

Comment: Bingo! (and embarrassingly enough I *did* know about `va_list` but totally forgot about that)

Comment: @YePhIcK: How is it possible to forget something you do not even know? ;)

Comment: quite simple: a typo in "did" turned it into a "didn't" :-P

Answer (score 0):

You *cannot* chain calls to C-style variadic functions. The only way is to pass `va_list` as an argument. This is exactly the reason why the v* family of functions is needed.

So you write your v*-like functions in terms of `va_list`, and *then* wrap each one in an ellipsis-based variadic function.